# Change date format for multiple records SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having old system which is developed in MS Access and I've a requirement to convert it a web application.

In the old application we have a MS Access Database and we need to import it to SQL Server.

Now there are many tables which have datetime columns with datatype as below:

**Access: LongText**

**SQL Server: nvarchar(MAX)**

I've successfully imported the MS Access database to SQL Server but now I'm stuck in datetime conversion issue.

There is a table which have around 86000 records and we need to convert it column to datatype **datetime**.

currently column have nvarchar(MAX) datatype with
**"dd-mm-yyyy"** and here is the screenshot for the same:

https://www.screencast.com/t/OP9edlsTdbR

I've tried to fix it by doing google but nothing work as expected.

Comment: Open the table in design mode by right clicking on the table and update the datatype to datetime. This should solve your problem.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/100743
This might be the answer to your question as well.

Comment: Firstly did that but it result an error with "The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert your all string values to appropriate style : 105 : dd-mm-yyyy

```
 ALTER TABLE dbo.TableName ALTER COLUMN DateNeed DATETIME NULL[NOT NULL]
    GO

 UPDATE TableName SET DateNeed =  CONVERT(DATETIME, DateNeed , 105)
```

Comment: Here is the output while executing first query:
https://www.screencast.com/t/IJgWwWREWfm

Comment: because field contains NULL value
:---
UPDATE TableName SET DateNeed =  CONVERT(DATETIME, DateNeed , 105) where DateNeed is not null

Comment: same error, but I think there is an issue with data..query seems correct.